# Carrierwave can not save new image after validation failed in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have tried many times to save new image after carrierwave keep file after validation fail, but not success.

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <label>My Avatar</label>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I had to sanitize parameter for :avatar, :avatar_cache, ...

It has still display new image ,but when i save the form the new image not saved.

Comment: Can you see which validation failed or what the validation error was?

Comment: not a lot to go on here im afraid, more details needed

Comment: TomKadwill I'm choose another image , and set user.name = nil and then I saved it , carrierwave still keep new image file , I continue set user.name = 'Peter' and saved it, but new image not saved.

Comment: avatar_cache = nil , when I update the use form.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `:avatar_cache` is included in your permitted params.